# How to pass data from action in controller, to the handlebar template in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My application.js controller has @actions for sending POST requests, and I want to take the json payload response from one of these actions, and use that json payload in my .hbs file called application.hbs.

```
@action async myFunctionn() {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/vnd.api+json'},
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(payload)});

    let json = await response.json();
    return;


}
```

How can I most simply do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the data fetched by that network request to a property on the component class, which is than used in the template:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default MyComponent extends Component {
  @tracked posts;

  @action
  async loadPosts() {
    let response = await fetch('http://examples.com/posts');
    let payload = await response.json();
    this.posts = payload.data;
  }
}
```

```
<button {{on "click" this.loadPosts}}>load posts</button>

{{#each this.posts as |post|}}
  <article>
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
  </article>
{{/if}}
```